# TransactionScope, EF DbContext, and Dirty Read

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, transactionscope

I've been Googling for an answer for the past few hours, but haven't found an answer, so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

I am wondering how to do a dirty read with EF DbContext (Code-First) within a TransactionScope.  For example

```
DbContext context = new MyEntities();
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    context.SomeTable.Add(someObject);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var objects = context.SomeTable.Where(...).Select(...); //times out here on the read, because the write above locks the tables
    //modify each object
    context.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete(); //transaction is a success only if the entire batch succeeds
}
```

I have tried wrapping the read call with the following:

```
using(TransactionScope scope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions{IsolationLEvel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted}))
{
    var objects = context.SomeTable.Where(...).Select(...); //times out here on the 
}
```

What is the proper approach?

Comment: What RDMS do you use? Normally writers should not block readers unless it's SQLServer . But even for SQLServer there is better solution than using dirty read - you can enable `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT `for database.

Comment: Also it looks like you're fishing for the inserted object's ID, there's easier way to do it than selecting it after the insert. Is this the case?

Comment: "times out here on the read, because the write above locks the tables" certainly not because the read is occurring in the same transaction. Why would a tran block itself? Also, the writes will not lock the entire table (which is a myth).

Comment: @SmartK8, not just the IDs, but retrieving previous objects in addition to the newly added ones, and performing some operation on them, so kinda need to do it in this order

Comment: @usr the savechanges call to the db has not been committed, appears the table is locked...if i call scope.complete before the read, it works, but then that negates the purpose of the transaction

Answer (score 1):

It has finally clicked for me what the problem is: EF is not integrating with `TransactionScope` the way L2S nicely does. This means that EF opens and closes the connection for each operation requiring the server (saving changes or querying).

This gets you distributed transactions and a distributed deadlock.

To solve this, manually open and close the EF `StoreConnection` to ensure that there is exactly one connection for the duration of the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the IsolationLevel for TransactionScope like this...

```
var transactionOptions = new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
using (var transactionScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute `alter database your_db_name set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT on;`(available from SQLServer 2005) on the server, and readers won't be blocked by writters (assuming reading transaction in `read committed` isolation level).

Comment: ah, yes, this sounds most logical...currently it is off, i will ask the DBAs to change this for me...